# How to use common resources in multiple resource dictionaries

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have some common resources like Brushes, Converers, etc that I want to use in multiple resource dictionaries:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Common.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/CustomStyles1.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/CustomStyles2.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Resources from Common.xaml references in CustomStyle1.xaml using `StaticResource` or `ThemeResource` markup extentions are not recognized unless I add Common.xaml to MergedDictionaries in CustomStyle1.xaml as well:

```
<!-- CustomStyles1.xaml -->
<ResourceDictionary
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Common.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

However, this loads Common.xaml each time I add it to MergedDictionaries and the resources are instanciated multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is why you reference the `Common.xaml` to `CustomSyle1.xaml` dictionary.

You have three dictionaries, the better way is that each of them contains different resources, and there're no dependencies between them. So that when in a page you should use one or two of them, merged them to the page resources and all the merged resources can be used.

If you do want to reference the `Common.xaml` to `CustomSyle1.xaml`, suppose once you need use `Common.xaml` as well as the `CustomStyle1.xaml` in one page , you only need to merge the `CustomStyle1.xaml` to the page resources since the `Common.xaml` has already merged to `CustomSyle1.xaml`. In that case you will not have the  multiple instantiated puzzle.

Comment: Common.xaml is called common, because it contains resources that are common. I need to reference it from CustomStyle1.xaml, CustomStyle2.xaml, etc..

For example, in each ResourceDictionary I want to use color resource called MyIconColor, or default value for control padding - Thickness recource called PaddingAll